Unable SSH/SFTP from Azure VM to On-Prem Linux Server with error “Key_exchange_identification : read connection time out, Banner exchange time out"
I'm currently facing an issue connecting via SSH and SFTP from an Azure VM (Windows Server 2022) to an on-premises Linux server (RedHat 8.9).
error_details_image
Here are the details:

Environment

Azure Firewall deployed between the Azure VM and the on-premises server
Site-to-Site VPN established for connectivity
SSH version for AzureVM : "OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.5p1, LibreSSL 3.8.2"
SSH version LinuxServer : "OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k FIPS 25 Mar 2021"


Connectivity Status

Networking is working fine between them validated by Test-NetConnection and Azure
Connection troubleshooter
Able to connect to the on-premises Linux server using WinSCP from the Azure VM.
Laptop, devices, Cloudera containers, another on-prem Linux machine, WinSCP and Putty all can ssh/sftp to the VM except built-in openssh in Windows.


Troubleshooting Steps and Findings:

ssh -vvv user@xxxxx: Fails with authentication error

ssh_error_details_image


Given that I can connect using WinSCP, and network diagnostics confirm no connectivity issues between the Azure VM and the on-premises Linux server.
Is there something specific I should check in the SSH configuration or authentication setup on the on-premises Linux server and Azure VM?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

SSH, SCP and SFTP are different things. When you can use SCP, that does not mean you can automatically get a SSH shell. Check /etc/ssh/sshd_config for the Subsystem and/or PermitTunnel lines, check if your user gets a (working) shell.
